# $this->pagination->create_links(); returning nothing

Tags: codeigniter

Link for pagination not working

This is my controller.

Here Is my code. What's wrong in this.
Here links are not Initialize. Tell me the correct solutions

The create_links(); the function seems to not be working. I don't get any errors, but it just returns a blank string. I'm aware the documentation says http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html The create_links() function returns an empty string when there is no pagination to show. but so how do I fix that? Thanks you!

```
public function Index()
{
       $this->load->model('Testmodel');
       $conf = array();
       $conf['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/user/view";
       $conf['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('user')->num_rows();
       $conf['per_page'] = 5;
       $conf['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
       $conf['num_links'] = 2;
       $conf['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
       $conf['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
       $conf['next_link'] = 'Next';
       $conf['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

       if($this->uri->segment(3)){
           $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
       }
       else{
           $page = 0;
       }
       $data['records'] = $this->Testmodel->fetch_data($conf['per_page'], $page);
            $this->pagination->initialize($conf);
            $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
}
```

Model Code:

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->select('user.*,country.countryName,state.stateName,city.cityName');
            $this->db->from('user');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
              foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
              }
              return $data;
            }
            return false;
```

Comment: where is this line `$this->load->library('pagination');`?

Comment: function __construct() { 
            parent::__construct(); 
            $this->load->library('pagination');
        }
HEre

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your code for the `views` where you used that `links`?